# Completely Canceling TCP Connection Timeout / Linger Time Mechanism to Use Same Port Again Instantly after it Closed

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to prevent TCP ports from waiting in TIME_WAIT state after it closed with following logic:

```
Socket sock = new Socket();
sock.setSoLinger(true, 0); // Set it as "0" before bind and connect.
sock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(clientAddress, clientPort));
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddress, serverPort), 8000);
// sock.close() will be called at the end.
```

After that I verified this port not waits in TIME_WAIT state in my local(Windows) and server side (RedHat Linux) with netstat. But I still couldn't bind to same clientPort without waiting for a while.

Note that clientAddress and clientPort taken from company VPN (Virtual Ethernet Adapter).

What is that am I missing here?

Comment: The TIME_WAIT state is caused by the OS I don't think you can change that in Java. For a ServerSocket you could set `setReuseAddress` to true to ignore the wait time but for a client socket I don't know.

Comment: @Robert the `Socket` class has a [`setReuseAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setReuseAddress-boolean-) method, too. The underling `SO_REUSEADDR` (and `SO_REUSEPORT`) option works for both clients and servers.

Comment: @BurakTopcu Do you *absolutely* need to `bind()` the client to a specific ip/port before calling `connect()`? Typically one lets the OS chose the ip and random port to connect from. If you are trying to ensure your client connects using a specific network adapter, you should be able to just `bind()` to the adapter ip and let the OS pick a random port for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I didn't try SO_REUSEPORT option.

Comment: The goal of reusing the same client port instantly cannot safely be met. It would violate a key part of TCP security. NB The `SO_LINGER`mechanism has nothing to do with the TIME_WAIT state. It provides a timeout on `close()` while there is still outbound data in flight. All that precedes the TIME_WAIT state, which starts after the socket is closed. It has no bearing on 'port in use' whatsoever. Setting it to `(true, 0)` as you have causes the connection to be *reset* on close, which loses all the data in flight. You don't want that. It can upset the peer as well.